# how to display JTextField in double form, not in the form of a string

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

for example:

```
double y = rs.getDouble ("a");
double z = rs.getDouble ("b");
double q = rs.getDouble ("c");
TextField2.setText (String.valueOf ((q * y) + z));
```

but if I take the data, then the result is like this:
3000.0 be a string instead of a double.

Comment: `DecimalFormat` or `JFormattedTextField`

Answer (score 2):

> how to display JTextField in double form, not in the form of a string

- to use proper `JComponent`

  1. [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with Number Formatter
  2. [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) with Number Formatter and SpinnerNumberModel

Comment: how to use JFormattedTextField or JSpinner with Number Formatter?

Comment: @user3111782 if you see when you click in the links he post, you can read the tutorials and there all is written, did you read them?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JFormattedTextField`

```
NumberFormat amountFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
amountFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
amountFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
JFormattedTextField textfield1 = new JFormattedTextField(amountFormat);
```

And instead of `setText()`, you would use `setValue(Object value)`, so you would do

```
double value = q * y + z;   // no need for paranthesis - order of operation
textfield2.setValue(new Double(value));
```

---

See [JFormattedTextField docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) | [Tuorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) | [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

---

Note, If you want currency conversion, you could use. [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28%29)